# Interpreting coefficient in a Diff-in-Diff (fixed effects model)

Tags: regression, inference, modeling, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I am running a DiD model with fixed effects to find the causal effect of traffic cameras on my outcome variable: share of car accidents of total accidents per neighborhood.

The treatment, road cameras, were randomly distributed in certain neighborhoods (i.e. the treatment group) versus neighborhoods without a road camera (i.e. the control group).

```
## declare data as panel, and run DiD model
xtset numeric_neighborhood month, monthly
xtreg car_accidents DiD_implementation month, fe cluster(numeric_neighborhood)
```

DiD_implementation is coded where it equals 1 if neighborhoods were exposed to treatment and the period is post-treatment, and 0 otherwise.
However, I am not sure how to interpret the coefficient here and whether it's a problem that my R square values are low?

```
gen DiD_implementation= treatment_time*treated_neighborhood
```

```
Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =     70,451
Group variable: numeric_ne~d                    Number of groups  =      2,321

R-squared:                                      Obs per group:
     Within  = 0.0071                                         min =          2
     Between = 0.0003                                         avg =       30.4
     Overall = 0.0027                                         max =        118

                                                F(2,2320)         =      77.55
corr(u_i, Xb) = -0.0642                         Prob > F          =     0.0000

                     (Std. err. adjusted for 2,321 clusters in numeric_neighborhood)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   |               Robust
 car_accidents | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
DiD_implementation |  -2.080575   .2743751    -7.58   0.000    -2.618621   -1.542529
             month |  -.0169323   .0024935    -6.79   0.000    -.0218221   -.0120425
             _cons |   4.489439    .140678    31.91   0.000     4.213571    4.765307
-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
```

My interpretation of the coefficient of car_accidents is that it's statistically significant at 0.00 p-value level and suggests car accidents declined by approximately 2.080 percentage points in treated neighbhorhoods, compared to neighborhoods were no traffic cameras were installed?

Comment: First, `DiD_implementation` *should* equal 1 for the neighborhoods installing cameras *and* only in the months after the cameras were installed. Presently, it seems like it’s the “treated areas” only, with no regard to pre-/post-treatment. Am I wrong? Also, wouldn’t lawmakers push for the installation of cameras in areas trending higher in traffic fatalities over time? Is the imposition of treatment really random?

Comment: Great questions, I have updated my post to clarify the DiD implementation variable, which takes into to account the treatment's period.

On the randomness, the cameras were intentionally distributed randomly as a pilot, and to avoid selection bias problems.

Comment: Good. Also, is your outcome a proportion? If so, then I assume the numerator is just the total number of accidents that involve *at least* one car?

Comment: Correct. So if there are 3 accidents in a given month and neighborhood, it would be:
3/100*100=3% is the share of car accidents.

Comment: Then the denominator is all reported accidents/collisions in that neighborhood and month? Do you observe that the share of accidents is very high across all areas, and months?

Comment: Yes to the first question. No, it varies by areas pre-treatment, but the selection of installing the cameras was done randomly as a pilot for the policy's effectiveness. Post-treatment, areas exposed to treatment had a lower share of car accidents relative to the control areas.